# Efficient way to select subset dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've 9.5M rows in a DataFrame of following form:

```
    Id | X | Y | Pass_Fail_Status
-------+---+---+-----------------
    w0 | 0 | 0 | Pass
    w0 | 0 | 1 | Fail
...
    w1 | 0 | 0 | Fail
...
 w6000 | 45| 45| Pass
```

What is the most **efficient** way  to select subset DataFrame for each "Id" and do processing with that?

As of now I'm doing following:

- I already have set of possible "Id"s from another DataFrame

```py
for id in uniqueIds:
    subsetDF = mainDF[mainDF["Id"] == id]
    predLabel = predict(subsetDF)
```

But this seems to have severe performance issue as there're 6.7K such possible id and each repeating 1.4K times. I've done some profiling using cProfile that does not point to this line but I see some scalar op call taking time which is has exact 6.7K call count.

EDIT2: The requirement for the subset-dataframe is that all rows should have same Id - finally for the training or predict 'Id' is not that important but the X,Y location and pass/fail in that location is important.

The subsetDF should be of following form:

```
        Id | X | Y | Pass_Fail_Status
    -------+---+---+-----------------
        w0 | 0 | 0 | Pass
        w0 | 0 | 1 | Fail
       ...
     w1399 | 0 | 0 | Fail
       ...
     w1399 |45 |45 | Pass
```

Comment: maybe you could use `isin`: `mainDF[mainDF["Id"].isin(uniqueIds)]`

Comment: uniqIds has all the ids from Id column of mainDF and I need subsetDF for each of these for training/prediction on each of those subsetDF. Hope I understand your point correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conclusion:

**Winner: `groupby`**
According to the result of my experiments, the most efficient way to select a subset DataFrame for each "Id" and do processing with is to use the `groupby` method.

### Code (Jupyter Lab):

#### # Preparation:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample dataframe
n = 6700 * 1400 # = 9380000
freq = 1400
mainDF = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': ['w{:04d}'.format(i//freq) for i in range(n)],
    'X': np.random.randint(0, 46, n),
    'Y': np.random.randint(0, 46, n),
    'Pass_Fail_Status': [('Pass', 'Fail')[i] for i in np.random.randint(0, 2, n)]
})
uniqueIds = set(mainDF['Id'])
```

#### # Experiments:

```py
# Experiment (a): apply pandas mask (the OP's method)
def exp_a():
    for _id in uniqueIds:
        subsetDF = mainDF[mainDF['Id'] == _id]
print('Experiment (a):')
%timeit exp_a()

# Experiment (b): use set_index
def exp_b():
    df_b = mainDF.set_index('Id')
    for _id in uniqueIds:
        subsetDF = df_b.loc[_id]
print('Experiment (b):')
%timeit exp_b()

# Experiment (c): use groupby
def exp_c():
    for _, subsetDF in mainDF.groupby('Id'):
        pass
print('Experiment (c):')
%timeit exp_c()
```

### Output:

```py
Experiment (a): # apply pandas mask (the OP's method)
39min 46s ± 992 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Experiment (b): # use set_index
1.19 s ± 7.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Experiment (c): # use groupby
997 ms ± 2.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Sample dataframe:

|  | Id | X | Y | Pass_Fail_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | w0000 | 9 | 28 | Fail |
| 1 | w0000 | 42 | 28 | Pass |
| 2 | w0000 | 26 | 36 | Pass |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| 9379997 | w6699 | 12 | 14 | Fail |
| 9379998 | w6699 | 8 | 40 | Fail |
| 9379999 | w6699 | 17 | 21 | Pass |

Comment: Thanks - I'll try the set_index approach on my data as well and check if it gives another 2-2.5X gain over 'groupby' on my data and accordingly update.

Comment: One comment on your experiments - each preprocessing like set_index etc. also should be timed (i.e. those should go inside the functions).

Comment: In that case, the experimental schema has to be totally changed, so I updated my whole code. The winner is `groupby` now.

Comment: This is how the data look for my case:  original 4234 sec, set_index: 1738 sec; groupby: 471 sec.

Comment: Wow, `groupby` is really fast! Good luck with your project:)

Comment: Just a note that this is really efficient for speeding up code. Using `groupby` in place of the pandas mask took my code from 97 minutes down to 70 seconds. Pity this questino hasn't had more traction as it's a common issue!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use `groupby` + [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) to randomly sample a certain fraction of the original `df` to split into `train` and `test` DataFrames:

```
train = df.groupby('Id').sample(frac=0.7)
test = df[~df.index.isin(train.index)]
```

For example, in the sample you have in the OP, the above code produces:

`train`:

```
      Id   X   Y Pass_Fail_Status
0     w0   0   0             Pass
2     w1   0   0             Fail
3  w6000  45  45             Pass
```

`test`:

```
   Id  X  Y Pass_Fail_Status
1  w0  0  1             Fail
```

Comment: Thanks ... the groupby() helped to improve the performance by 6X. I'm posting my solution below.

Comment: @soumeng78 great. you could upvote the answer if you found it helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the suggestion for 'groupby' by both 'enke' and 'quasi-human'. It improved the overall performance (including other operations) by 6X (I measured the numbers 3 times for each approaches and this gain is based on avg) - now the for loop is like following:

```python
   for id, subsetDF in mainDF.groupby("Id", as_index=False):
        predLabel = predict(subsetDF)
```